# Xcode remove large number of category warnings with refactoring

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c-category, linker-warning

I want to remove warnings from an older project that somebody else has written.

I am confronted with over 200+ warnings about an instance method in a category overrides a method from class.

---

So for example:

In  header:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
    //...unimportant code
@end

@interface Foo()
    @property(nonatomic, retain)NSArray *bar;
@end

@interface Foo (Private)
    //...unimportant code
@end
```

In body:

```
@implementation Foo
    //...unimportant code
@end

@implementation Foo (Private)
- (NSArray*)bar
{
    //...
}
@end
```

Generated linker waring:

*ld: warning: instance method 'bar' in category from Foo.o overrides method from class in Foo.o*

---

So obviously the getter for the *bar* property is implemented in the wrong category.

I can solve the problem if I copy the method in the category above.

But do I have to do this manually in over 200 classes?

Or does a refactoring tool for this problem exist or does a flag for the linker exist to suppress exactly this type of warning?

Comment: What happens when you change the private declaration to look like `@interface Foo()` and move the private implementation into the (public) `@implementation` section?

Comment: This works too, but also here it would take a long time to change the 200+ classes by hand.